# Background in HTML Won't Change According To Variable Number

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple game where the background will change every 20 jumps. There is this one problem. When the jump counter reaches 20, the background will not change. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried to use "document.getElementById('sample').innerhtml" to change the CSS code to an updated CSS that changes the background. It doesn't seem to be working. I checked the JavaScript console and all it says is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at index.html:15". Currmtly a button is used to test the jumping.

Here is the whole document: (I know it is quite mess)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Background Slide Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jump_count = 0;
        //Mechanics for the character to jump (Jump counter and character movement)
        function incline(){
            jump_count++;
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "<h1 class='counter'>Jump Count: " + jump_count + "</h1>";
            document.getElementById('jump_animation').innerHTML = ".jump{animation:jump 0.4s linear;}@keyframes jump{0%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}50%{transform:translate3d(0, -300px, 0);}100%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}}";
        }
        //If, else if, else: Changes the scene according to amount of jumps
        if (jump_count < 20){
            //This willchange the background to be 'field.png'
            document.getElementById('background').innerHTML = "html{background-color:black;animation:day_cycle 180s linear infinite;}.background{background:url('test.png') repeat-x;height:100%;width:3050px;animation:slide 3s linear infinite;}@keyframes slide{0%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}100%{transform:translate3d(-1600px, 0, 0);}}@keyframes day_cycle{0% {background-color:#0063fd;}15% {background-color:orange;}30% {background-color:red;}45% {background-color:#4B0082;}60% {background-color:red;}75% {background-color:orange;}100% {background-color:#0062fd;}}";
        } else if (jump_count > 20 && jump_count < 40){
            document.getElementById('background').innerHTML = "html{background-color:black;animation:day_cycle 180s linear infinite;}.background{background:url('field.png') repeat-x;height:100%;width:3050px;animation:slide 3s linear infinite;}@keyframes slide{0%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}100%{transform:translate3d(-1600px, 0, 0);}}@keyframes day_cycle{0% {background-color:#0063fd;}15% {background-color:orange;}30% {background-color:red;}45% {background-color:#4B0082;}60% {background-color:red;}75% {background-color:orange;}100% {background-color:#0062fd;}}";
        } else {
            //Nothing happens
        }
        //This is where when the space button is pressed, the sprite will jump
 //This does nothing yet
        function space(){
            if (e.key === 37){
                jump_count++;
            } else {
                //Nothing will happen
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .counter{
            position:absolute;
            z-index:4;
            right:50px;
            top:15px;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" id="background">
        html{
            background-color:black;
            animation:day_cycle 180s linear infinite;
        }
        .background_class{
            background:url("test.png") repeat-x;
            height:100%;
            width:3050px;
            animation:slide 3s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes slide{
            0%{
                transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
            100%{
                transform:translate3d(-1600px, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        @keyframes day_cycle{
            0% {background-color:#0063fd;}
            15% {background-color:orange;}
            30% {background-color:red;}
            45% {background-color:#4B0082;}
            60% {background-color:red;}
            75% {background-color:orange;}
            100% {background-color:#0062fd;}
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" id="jump_animation">
        .jump{
            animation:jump 0.4s linear;
        }
        @keyframes jump{
            0%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
            50%{transform:translate3d(0, -300px, 0);}
            100%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <audio autostart loop hidden>
            <source src="track 1.wav" type="audio/wav">
        </audio>
        <img src="character_sprite.gif" alt="sprite" style="position:absolute;top:290px;left:75px;z-index:3;" class="jump">
        <div id="counter">
            <!--The Jump counter within the top-right corner-->
            <h1 class="counter">Jump Count: 0</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="background_class" id='background'></div>
        <button onclick="incline()">Increment Test</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at index.html:15". Would mean that it did not find the element you were trying to get. Use `console.log( document.getElementById('sample'));` to check the output... If the element is indeed not found, then double check your html id's. One possible error I see is that you have 2 of the same id's."background" that should never happen

Comment: I see that now. I will fix it and see if anything changes

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: So I had changed one of the background IDs to "background_class" but now there is no background that appears. I have double checked the file directory and everything is correct.

Comment: Try to remove the html from the if (jump_count < 20){.... Else... And add some console logs to see what happens when you click the button. If it works fine its probably the .innerHtml that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this part:

```
    if (jump_count < 20){
        //This willchange the background to be 'field.png'
        document.getElementById('background').innerHTML = "html{background-color:black;animation:day_cycle 180s linear infinite;}.background{background:url('test.png') repeat-x;height:100%;width:3050px;animation:slide 3s linear infinite;}@keyframes slide{0%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}100%{transform:translate3d(-1600px, 0, 0);}}@keyframes day_cycle{0% {background-color:#0063fd;}15% {background-color:orange;}30% {background-color:red;}45% {background-color:#4B0082;}60% {background-color:red;}75% {background-color:orange;}100% {background-color:#0062fd;}}";
    } else if (jump_count > 20 && jump_count < 40){
        document.getElementById('background').innerHTML = "html{background-color:black;animation:day_cycle 180s linear infinite;}.background{background:url('field.png') repeat-x;height:100%;width:3050px;animation:slide 3s linear infinite;}@keyframes slide{0%{transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);}100%{transform:translate3d(-1600px, 0, 0);}}@keyframes day_cycle{0% {background-color:#0063fd;}15% {background-color:orange;}30% {background-color:red;}45% {background-color:#4B0082;}60% {background-color:red;}75% {background-color:orange;}100% {background-color:#0062fd;}}";
    } else {
        //Nothing happens
    }
```

That part of the script isn't wrapped in a function, so it executes immediately. Since the script tag is inside the head, it executes without waiting for the page to be ready. So the `background` element doesn't exist yet.

You could put that part in a handler for the page's `ready` event, but the easiest thing to do is just move the whole `script` tag to the end of the body.

**Demo:**

- Your code as-is (with the TypeError): https://jsfiddle.net/g1vLbf8a/
- Script moved to the end of the body (no TypeError): https://jsfiddle.net/bemt2z0u/